# What does "to revive the 2-for-1 model" mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, colloquialisms

What does "find a clever way to revive the 2-for-1 model pitched by the Clintons so long ago" mean in the following quote from *The Washington Post* of today?

The author, Michelle Cottle, wrote that Obama’s

> Ivy League degrees, career success and general aura as an
>   ass-kicking, do-it-all superwoman had some women fantasizing that she
>   would, if not find a clever way to revive the 2-for-1 model pitched by
>   the Clintons so long ago, at least lean in and speak out on a variety
>   of tough issues. It was not to be.

Answer (score 5):

A contrast is being drawn between the roles of Barack and Michelle Obama, and those of Bill and Hillary Clinton two decades ago.

*Two-for-one* ordinarily refers to a promotional discount offered by a store or a vendor: the customer pays for one item and receives two (an alternative phrasing is *buy-one-get-one-free* deal or *BOGO* after the initials. Bill Clinton stated during his 1992 presidential campaign that by electing him, voters would get “[two for the price of one](http://www.ourwhitehouse.org/firstladyevolution.html#from%20first%20lady),” meaning that voters would get two accomplished policymakers even though only one was being elected— himself and his wife, Hillary. Hillary Clinton had trained as a lawyer and worked both as a policymaker and as an attorney; she would be the first First Lady who held a postgraduate degree. And indeed, he appointed her to chair his task force on health care reform, which was originally his top legislative priority.

This raised quite a bit of controversy, and after its failure, she quietly withdrew to more traditional roles until the very end of Bill Clinton's second term. The women Cottle writes of understood that the “Billary” model was politically risky, and so Michelle Obama would not have been given such an important official role. They are nevertheless disappointed that she has not at least spoken out on policy issues, despite her own impressive academic and professional credentials that would lend credibility to her positions. Instead, she has remained in the more traditional First Lady role, promoting broadly popular and relatively apolitical causes— specifically, fighting childhood obesity.

Answer (score 4):

Hilary Clinton was very active in policy and took on hard and controversial issues (notably healthcare), acting almost as a second president due to her intelligence and experience. Michelle Obama has similar creds but is not acting as much like a policy wonk/second president as much as a typical first lady, taking on politically safe social causes that are often neglected.

So, the 2-for-1 means you get two stong leaders although only 1 of them was actually elected.